# Timothy Gowers's Proof That the Rational Numbers Form a Countable Set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, rational-numbers

In his [blog](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/recognising-countable-sets/), Timothy Gowers gave the following proof:

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, he's proven that the rational numbers form a countable set by demonstrating that they can be written as the countable union of finite sets. In this case, it would be the countable union of all pre-images, right?

However, I'm having trouble following the proof. Specifically, the claim that the number of preimages of $n$ is certainly no more than $(2n + 1)^2$.

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: That is right. To see where $(2n+1)^2$ comes from note that we must have $-n \le p,q \le n$.

Comment: Try this for $n=3$  How many fractions can you come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preimages of $n$ look like $p/q$, where $|p|+|q|=n$ and $q > 0$. This means $-n \leq q \leq n$ and $-n \leq p \leq n$, giving $(2n+1)$ choices for $p$ and $(2n+1)$ choices for $q$, for a total of $(2n+1)^2$ choices of preimage.

Of course, the number of preimages may well be less than this: it is also certainly no more than $(n+1)(2n+1)$, but the proof works exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So this isn't counting the fact that we must have $q > 0$?

Comment: Right, the count can be improved. There are at most $2n-1$ choices for $p$ (since $q>0$), and at most $n$ choices for $q$. And even then, it could be further improved, but an exact count isn't required.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thanks all.

Comment: I'll be honest.  I'm a bit confused.  If $|p|+|q|=n$ then aren't there only $2$ choices for $p$ given $n$ and $q$ (i.e. $p = \pm(n-q)$ and as there are $n$ choices of $q$ given $n$ (i.e. $0 < q \le n$) aren't there at most $2n - 1$ choices for $r$?  Of course, there is no harm in overkill but $2n-1 < (2n+1)^2$ is a *lot* of overkill.  Is noting that $p$ and $q$ are dependent *that* much of a distraction?  IMO $(2n+1)$ because $-n \le q \le n$ (even though we *know* $0 < q \le n$ and $-n \le p \le n$ (even though we *know* $p  =\pm (n -q)$ is *soo* loose as to be very *UN*clear and confusing.